# dynamic button from dynamic button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, dynamic

Could someone please explain me something? I'm writing a really simple web form (C# aspx) and I'm using dynamic buttons. I create first button and add click event to it - no problem - everything works. But when I create a second dynamic button in event handler of my first button - I can't add event handler to it. I mean I can - there is no error - but I can never reach it.

In code below - when I load page - I see a button. I click it - and a new button is added. I click the second button - and it does nothing. (?)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // on PageLoad I create a dynamic button named b1
    Button b1 = new Button();
    b1.Text = "new 1";
    b1.Click += new EventHandler(b1_Click);
    div_data.Controls.Add(b1);
    // div_data is just a HTML div tag
}

void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // when I click dynamid button b1 - a new dynamic button b2 is created
    Button b2 = new Button();
    b2.Text = "new 2";
    b2.Click += new EventHandler(b2_Click);
    div_data.Controls.Add(b2);
}

void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this code is never executed... why ???
}
```

thanks for suggestions - and sorry if it's a noob question ;-)

Comment: Hi @Michael can you post what your code looks like in debugger once the second button is added.

Comment: Why you need to create them dynamically? Create them declaratively and make them visible/invisible as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All controls and every other object are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. 
That means you have to re-create them on postback. You're doing that already for the button `Button` in `Page_Load` but not with the button `b2` which was created in the fist button's event handler.

But the real question is: Why you need to create them dynamically? 
Create them declaratively(on the aspx-markup) and make them visible/invisible as needed.

Comment: It makes sense... as to why I make them dynamic - no other reason than "I wanted to try that way". I'll try with the visibility of my dynamic controls - thanks for suggestion ;-)